# Select children elements based on class in iteration

Tags: javascript, jquery

Either using Vanilla Javascript or jQuery.

```
// html
<input type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="patient[event_type_ids][]" id="patient_event_type_ids_1"> Bleeding puncture
<div data-target="patient_event_type_ids_1" class="form-sub">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" value="true" name="patient[blood_aspirated]" id="patient_blood_aspirated_true"> Yes
    <input type="radio" value="false" checked="checked" name="patient[blood_aspirated]" id="patient_blood_aspirated_false"> No
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" value="positive" name="patient[iv_test]" id="patient_iv_test_positive"> Positive
    <input type="radio" value="negative" checked="checked" name="patient[iv_test]" id="patient_iv_test_negative"> Negative
  </div>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" value="1" checked="checked" name="patient[event_type_ids][]" id="patient_event_type_ids_2"> Vascular puncture
<div data-target="patient_event_type_ids_2" class="form-sub">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" value="true" name="patient[abc]" id="patient_abc_true"> Yes
    <input type="radio" value="false" checked="checked" name="patient[abc]" id="patient_abc_false"> No
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="radio" value="positive" name="patient[xyz]" id="patient_xyz_positive"> Positive
    <input type="radio" value="negative" checked="checked" name="patient[xyz]" id="patient_xyz_negative"> Negative
  </div>
</div>

// javascript
var subForms = $('.form-sub');

subForms.each(function() {
  var subForm = this;
  var parentForm = '#' + subForm.dataset.target;

  if ($(parentForm).prop('checked')) {
    $(subForm).show();
  } else {
    $(subForm).hide();
  }

  $(parentForm).change(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked")) {
      $(subForm).show();
    } else {
      $(subForm).hide();
      $(':input')
        .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
        .removeAttr('checked')
        .removeAttr('selected')
        .not(':checkbox, :radio, select')
        .val('');
    }
  });
});
```

I want to clear all `input` when the checkbox is unchecked. The line `$(':input')` is definitely, but that's where I should select the responding `input`s which are the children of `.form-sub`. How do I do that in Javascript?

Comment: what problem you are facing in your current script?

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Didn't manage to select the `input` after `.form-sub`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace this line

```
var parentForm = '#' + subForm.dataset.target;
```

by

```
var parentForm = $( subForm ).prev();
```

and update the `change` event as

```
 if ( parentForm.prop('checked')) {
    $(subForm).show();
  } else {
    $(subForm).hide();
  }

  parentForm.change(function(){
    if($(this).prop("checked")) {
      $(subForm).show();
    } else {
      $(subForm).find(':input')
        .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
        .removeAttr('checked')
        .removeAttr('selected')
        .not(':checkbox, :radio, select')
        .val('');
      $(subForm).hide();
    }
  });
```

Comment: It works, but `$(subForm).hide();` must come after `$(subForm).find(':input')...`. Thanks!

Comment: Crap, that means I was doing it right all the time, but it was the `.hide` blocking. mtfk.